# Sorting data according to priority from Firebase and displaying it in a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data coming in from a realtime database and it's being bound to a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` as of now the data is being fetched in the way it's been ordered when the data was inserted in the realtime database but after I sort it by category or search the order is becoming scattered.

I have added a field called priority from where I want to assign the first item to be displayed and so on. How do I go about doing this, I need control over the order in which the user sees the items.

Here is an image of the realtime database and all it's fields. I want it to order by the child - priority.

[image]

I have also added the code below, which I used to bind to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

```
package com.test.testbv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mRef;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // User is signed in.
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            redirectToLogin();
        }

        // Action Bar

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Coupons List");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // Set Layout
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Send Query to Firebase Db
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.row,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.clickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                // get Data from firebase at the position clicked
                                String mTitle = getItem(position).getTitle();
                                String mDesc = getItem(position).getDescription();
                                String mImage = getItem(position).getImage();

                                // Pass this data to new activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                                intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                                intent.putExtra("description", mDesc);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                            }

                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };
        // Set adapter to recycler view
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may wish to check out the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data - you can use the `orderByChild('priority')` on the `mRef` - to achieve the desired sorting by field `priority`

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you should use a query that look like this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
Query mQuery = mRef.orderByChild("prority");
```

If you want to query for a particular priority, let's say for priority `1`, please use the followng query:

```
Query mQuery = mRef.orderByChild("prority").equalsTo(1);
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something very similar to this. Instead of declaring this on `onCreate`, I just added `mRef.orderByChild("priority")` in the `onStart`

Comment: It doesn't matter the place where you are declaring the query since it is correct.